# Why let and var bindings behave differently using setTimeout function?

Tags: javascript, var, let

This code logs `6`, 6 times:

```
(function timer() {
  for (var i=0; i<=5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function clog() {console.log(i)}, i*1000);
  }
})();
```

But this code...

```
(function timer() {
  for (let i=0; i<=5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function clog() {console.log(i)}, i*1000);
  }
})();
```

... logs the following result:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Why?

Is it because `let` binds to the inner scope each item differently and `var` keeps the latest value of `i`?

Comment: See here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/javascript-let-keyword-vs-var-keyword

Comment: It's worth noting that there are difference between the old Mozilla implementation of `let` and the new ES2015 version.  However, for the specifics of this question, the dupe answers it just fine.

Comment: Not a duplicate in my opinion. Every time somebody askes about let or var, we cant point to them to a very general answer. This is specifically asking about setTimeout(), which creates a 'closure within a loop' - a common var hoisting problem scenario - the answer and example below is not detailed in the linked duplicate accepted answer

Comment: Closely related: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

With **`var`** you have a function scope, and only one shared binding for all of your loop iterations - i.e. the `i` in every setTimeout callback means **the same** variable that **finally** is equal to 6 after the loop iteration ends.

With **`let`** you have a block scope and when used in the `for` loop you get a new binding for each iteration - i.e. the `i` in every setTimeout callback means **a different** variable, each of which has a different value: the first one is 0, the next one is 1 etc.

So this:

```
(function timer() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function clog() { console.log(i); }, i * 1000);
  }
})();
```

is equivalent to this using only var:

```
(function timer() {
  for (var j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
    (function () {
      var i = j;
      setTimeout(function clog() { console.log(i); }, i * 1000);
    }());
  }
})();
```

using immediately invoked function expression to use function scope in a similar way as the block scope works in the example with `let`.

It could be written shorter without using the `j` name, but perhaps it would not be as clear:

```
(function timer() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    (function (i) {
      setTimeout(function clog() { console.log(i); }, i * 1000);
    }(i));
  }
})();
```

And even shorter with arrow functions:

```
(() => {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    (i => setTimeout(() => console.log(i), i * 1000))(i);
  }
})();
```

(But if you can use arrow functions, there's no reason to use `var`.)

This is how Babel.js translates your example with `let` to run in environments where `let` is not available:

```
"use strict";

(function timer() {
  var _loop = function (i) {
    setTimeout(function clog() {
      console.log(i);
    }, i * 1000);
  };

  for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    _loop(i);
  }
})();
```

Thanks to [Michael Geary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1202830/michael-geary) for posting the link to Babel.js in the comments. See the link in the comment for a live demo where you can change anything in the code and watch the translation taking place immediately. It's interesting to see how other ES6 features get translated as well.

Comment: Just to add to your excellent explanation, here is a [translation of the ES6 code to ES5 provided by babeljs.io](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=(function%20timer()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20for%20(let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%3D%205%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(function%20clog()%20%7B%20console.log(i)%3B%20%7D%2C%20i%20*%201000)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)()%3B).

Comment: @MichaelGeary Thanks for the link. I added the Babel translation to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Scoping is not relevant here, it's down to the new binding created at each iteration

Answer (score 11):

Technically it's how @rsp explains in his excellent answer. This is how I like to understand things work under the hood. For the first block of code using `var`

```
(function timer() {
  for (var i=0; i<=5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function clog() {console.log(i)}, i*1000);
  }
})();
```

You can imagine the compiler goes like this inside the for loop

```
 setTimeout(function clog() {console.log(i)}, i*1000); // first iteration, remember to call clog with value i after 1 sec
 setTimeout(function clog() {console.log(i)}, i*1000); // second iteration, remember to call clog with value i after 2 sec
setTimeout(function clog() {console.log(i)}, i*1000); // third iteration, remember to call clog with value i after 3 sec
```

and so on

since `i` is declared using `var`, when `clog` is called, the compiler finds the variable `i` in the nearest function block which is `timer` and since we have already reached the end of the `for` loop, `i` holds the value 6, and execute `clog`. That explains 6 being logged six times.