# Piece of code that creates .json files, does not work

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, api

I have this code, the thing with it is, I need it to get some data from that website, the string in **apiurl**. This code needs to download these websites, with the certain appids found in the json. It needs to download the data on these websites and store them in a json file. For some reason this does not work.

I have this piece of code in a .js file:

```js
var gamekeys = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('gamekeys.json'));
var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(gamekeys, null, 4);

UpdateGamePricelist();

function UpdateGamePricelist() {
 for(var i = 0;i<gamekeys.keys.length;i++) {
  appid = gamekeys.keys[i].appid;
  
  var apiurl = "http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids="+appid;
  
  if (i < 95) {
   
   request(apiurl, function(err, response, body) {
    if (err) {
     console.log("Error when updating game prices: " + err+"\n");
     return;
    }
    
    var apiresponse = JSON.parse(body);
    if (body == "") {
     console.log("Could not find a pricelist m8");
     return;
    }
    
    fs.writeFile("C:/Users/ahmad/Desktop/Bots/SteamKeyProfitter/gamespricelist/"+appid+".json", body, function(err) {
     if(err) {
      console.log("Error saving data to game pricelist: " + err);
      return;
     }
     console.log("Game pricelist has been updated!");
    });
   });
  }
 }
}
```

And I have a json file, the json file called **gamekeys.json**

Here it is:

```
{
    "keys": [
            {
                "appid": 10,
                "price":0, 
                "listofkeys":[], 
                "game": "Counter-Strike"
            },
            {
                "appid": 20,
                "price":0, 
                "listofkeys":[], 
                "game": "Team Fortress Classic"
            },
            {
                "appid": 30,
                "price":0, 
                "listofkeys":[], 
                "game": "Day of Defeat"
            },
            {
                "appid": 40,
                "price":0, 
                "listofkeys":[], 
                "game": "Deathmatch Classic"
            },
```

It ofcourse keeps going (2 million lines of that)

Why does the first code not create 95 json files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems is that your `appid` is the same for all of the `writeFile` invocations.

Try changing:

```
appid = gamekeys.keys[i].appid;
```

to:

```
let appid = gamekeys.keys[i].appid;
```

You need a fresh binding for all of the callbacks or otherwise they all get the same value (from the last loop iteration). Note that `var` would not work here, you need `let`. If you use `i` in one of the closures then you also need to use `for (let i = ...)` instead of `for (var i = ...)`

`apiurl` can be declared with `var` because its value is passed to the `request()` invocation instead of being captured by a closure, but if you use `let` alle of the time and never use `var` you wouldn't have to worry about it.

If you always start every program with `'use strict';` (with quotes) and never use `var` (using `let` or `const` instead) then you will not have problems with the scoping that you have here, so it's a good practice to follow and enforce with linters.

This is one of the problems. There may be more but this is certainly one of them.

### Update

Answering the comment by Alex "why can't he use var appid"

Run this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  let appid = 'ID' + i;
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(appid);
  }, 500 * i);
}
```

And run this program:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var appid = 'ID' + i;
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(appid);
  }, 500 * i);
}
```

And compare the output.

This demonstrates the difference between `let` and `var`.

See this answer for more info about the difference between `let` and `var`:

- [Why let and var bindings behave differently using setTimeout function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31285911/why-let-and-var-bindings-behave-differently-using-settimeout-function/31286220#31286220)

Comment: why can't he use `var appid` the only reason it doesn't currently work is that `appid` is hoisted to the global scope because he doesn't have a `var` declaration.   I thought `let` transpiles to `var` anyway and `let` only works with `strict` mode enabled to not allow the constant to be redefined.

Comment: @Alex You don't use `let` but `const` if you don't want constants to be redefined. The difference between `let` and `var` is block scope vs function scope. See my updated answer for an example and see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31285911/why-let-and-var-bindings-behave-differently-using-settimeout-function/31286220#31286220) for more details and for explanation to what *actually* `let` got transpiled to.

Comment: that makes sense, so because there is a setTimeout in that block we use `let` to bind `i` to the context of that current iteration of the loop as after 500ms `i` is `3` because the loop has finished executing but there are 4 tasks scheduled in the event queue to be processed where `i` is `3` in that lexical scope.   Gotcha, I never actually considered this before, really useful to know. cheers :)