# using setTimeout with var and let - different results

Tags: javascript

Why the following code returns 10 times 10 and print `hey` as first line?

```
   for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 0)
    }
    console.log('hey')
```

When if instead I use `let` I get properly the counting, but why the line `hey` is always printed first?

```
 for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 0)
    }
    console.log('hey')
```

My question actually contains two:

- First why `hey` is printed first.
- Why using `let` the counting is printed properly.

Comment: Not sure if this answer my question, also does not cover setTimeout

Comment: There's nothing special about `setTimeout`. The difference is just in whether each closure gets the same or a different binding of `i`, which is because of the difference between the scopes of `let` and `var`.

Comment: Doesn't matter, the timeout is irrelevant here, the reason it works is because `let` is block scoped and works in the "infamous closure inside loop" issue

Comment: Why is that a duplicate? He's asking why the different position of `Hey` in the two examples. It would seem like `hey` should always be printed before the `setTimeout` callbacks.

Comment: @spanky He's asking two questions. The difference between `let` and `var` is in the title, so that's presumably his main question, and the other was an aside.

Comment: I see. Well the "aside" seems more interesting. I thought that even with a `0` timer, there should still be async behavior. Maybe the console is async too?

Comment: maybe related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31285911/why-let-and-var-bindings-behave-differently-using-settimeout-function

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout() is an asynchronous function

```
console.log('hey')
```

won't wait for it to finish before printing, since JS is single threaded, it would wait for the program to run and then pick the setTimeout() from event queue

difference between let and var can be found in this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable). Basically since let has scope limited to the for loop, the setTimeout can refer to only 1 value of i. If we use var then it is function scope and each function would get the same value of i