# Can somebody explain what below excerpt means from a javascript post?

Tags: javascript

I am copying an excerpt from Javascript post. Need to know what exactly author is trying to convey.

> In loops, you get a fresh binding for each iteration if you
>   let-declare a variable. The loops that allow you to do so are: for,
>   for-in and for-of.
>
> This looks as follows:
>
> ```
> let arr = [];
> for (let i=0; i < 3; i++) {
>     arr.push(() => i);
> }
>
> console.log(arr.map(x => x())); // [0,1,2]
> ```
>
> In contrast, a var declaration leads to a single binding for the whole
>   loop (a const declaration works the same):
>
> ```
> let arr = [];
> for (var i=0; i < 3; i++) {
>     arr.push(() => i);
> }
>
> console.log(arr.map(x => x())); // [3,3,3]
> ```
>
> Getting a fresh binding for each iteration may seem strange at first,
>   but it is very useful whenever you use loops to create functions (e.g.
>   callbacks for event handling) that refer to loop variables.

Comment: The author explains it pretty properly. What is your exact question about this?

Comment: I was trying to understand binding. Got the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31285911/why-let-and-var-bindings-behave-differently-using-settimeout-function

Answer (score 0):

Basically `let` makes a new variable each loop so the array it's pushed to won't have the same value in each index as it would with `var` since all index arrays would point to the same variable.