# For loop does not work correctly because of setTimeout

Tags: javascript

Loop works fine without setTimeout but not with it. What caused it? Thanks you in advance

```js
const sentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";

for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(
            `The character at index ${i} is ${sentence.charAt(i)}`
        );
    }, (i + 1) * 100);
}
```

Comment: It should be `let i = 0`?

Comment: check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31286220/4540673

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#description) instead of `var`:

```
const sentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";

for (let i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(
            `The character at index ${i} is ${sentence.charAt(i)}`
        );
    }, (i + 1) * 100);
}
```

Another way could utilize the fact that setTimeout can pass arguments to the function that will be called:

```
const sentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";

for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
    setTimeout((x) => {
        console.log(
            `The character at index ${x} is ${sentence.charAt(x)}`
        );
    }, (i + 1) * 100, i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because before you started printing, the variable i has reached to value 44 already. That's why it printed 44. and at index 44, there is no char, that's why no char showed.